# Is it required to check before replacing a string in StringBuilder (using functions like "Contains" or "IndexOf")?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Is there any method IndexOf or Contains in C#. Below is the code:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(mystring);
sb.Replace("abc", "a");
string dateFormatString = sb.ToString();

if (sb.ToString().Contains("def"))
{
    sb.Replace("def", "aa");
}


if (sb.ToString().Contains("ghi"))
{
    sb.Replace("ghi", "assd");
}
```

As you might have noticed I am using ToString() above again and again which I want to avoid as it is creating new string everytime. Can you help me how can I avoid it?

Comment: Why don't you just replace without checking for contains, as it should ignore the text anyway if it does not contain the string you are looking for

Comment: RE: "Is there any method IndexOf or Contains in C#". C# is a programming language. The language itself does not define any specific methods, weather it IndexOf, Contains or any other. Instead, C# give you a way to define your methods as you see fit. You can read more about it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx Methods in .NET belong to types and types are normally language agnostic - you can create them in any language that support types.

Comment: It's quite easy to find whether particular type has or does not have a method with a given name, by looking at MSDN. In case of StringBuilder class the article is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx, as you can easily see from this article, this class does not contain neither IndexOf nor Contains methods. With more obscure cases you might want to use .NET Reflector for picking under the hood and seeing what methods a class might have.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the `StringBuilder` *doesn't* contain "def" then performing the replacement won't cause any problems, so just use:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(mystring);
sb.Replace("abc", "a");
sb.Replace("def", "aa");
sb.Replace("ghi", "assd");
```

Comment: This is also a good idea from an efficiency perspective.  Doing a `Contains` and then a `Replace` means you're searching the string twice.  From a high-level perspective, "Replace all instances of `"def"` with `"aa"` " still makes sense if there are no instances of `"def"`.

Comment: What if the new string is a method that generates the string? So `sb.Replace("abc", GenerateReplacement())` will the method `GenerateReplacement()` be executed only if `"abc"` exists?

Comment: @Ricketts: No - think about what that code is turned into: the `GenerateReplacement()` method is called, and then the result is passed into `Replace` as an argument.

Comment: **That doesn't answer the question** - the question was about `.IndexOf` for StringBuilder ...

Comment: @Matt: It answers the aim behind the top-level question, to the OP's satisfaction. It's not an answer I'd give these days, but it does address what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I agree, but if that was the question, then the title should be changed. Or the question should be rephrased. Reason is  that I was looking for IndexOf in StringBuilder and found this question... but the high-voted answer wasn't answering what I was looking for.

Comment: @Matt: Go ahead, should you wish. This is effectively an X-Y problem, where I answered the Y because it was obvious enough given the description.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I think that the question fits better now.

Answer (score 5):

There's no such method in `StringBuilder` but you don't need the `Contains` tests. You can simply write it like this:

```
 sb.Replace("abc", "a");
 sb.Replace("def", "aa");
 sb.Replace("ghi", "assd");
```

If the string in the first parameter to `Replace` is not found then the call to `Replace` is a null operation—exactly what you want.

The documentation states:

> Replaces all occurrences of a specified string in this instance with another specified string.

The way you read this is that when there are no occurrences, nothing is done.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you don't have to use StringBuilder in this case... StringBuilder is more useful when used in a loop. Like Microsoft say in [In this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

> The String object is immutable. Every
>   time you use one of the methods in the
>   System.String class, you create a new
>   string object in memory, which
>   requires a new allocation of space for
>   that new object. In situations where
>   you need to perform repeated
>   modifications to a string, the
>   overhead associated with creating a
>   new String object can be costly. The
>   System.Text.StringBuilder class can be
>   used when you want to modify a string
>   without creating a new object. For
>   example, using the StringBuilder class
>   **can boost performance when
>   concatenating many strings together in
>   a loop**

So simply you can use String and avoid use ToString()...